# IOS, Swift: UIScrollView zoom

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, zooming

I am a beginner. I am unable to solve the following problem:
I would like to place a lot of buttons in a page. These buttons must appear in small size, but must have a possibility to zoom in for clicking on these items. I tried the following without success:

```
class myViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myArray =
            [["O","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"],
             ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13"],
             ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13"],
             ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13"]]

        var buttonY: CGFloat = 50

        for index in 0...myArray.count-1 {
            buttonY = buttonY + 45
            var buttonX: CGFloat = 10
            for (index2, myArraytxt) in myArray[index].enumerate() {
                let myButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: buttonX, y: buttonY, width: 30, height: 30))
                buttonX = buttonX + 40
                myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
                myButton.setTitle(myArraytxt, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                myButton.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
                }
                self.scrollView.addSubview(myButton)
            }
        self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.4
        self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0
        self.scrollView.zoomScale = 0.4
    }

    func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return self.view
    }
}
```

Any help or idea is appreciated!
Regards: Zoltan

Comment: try minimumZoomScale = 0.1 , maximumZoomScale = 4.0 and zoomScale = 1.0

Comment: zoom your button not the scrollView as i can suggest you.